# Change Web Api 2 Post method to accept modified body

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

Currently I have an API that is receiving an object type as below.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Job job) {}
```

When receiving a straight (or partial) object which matches the `Job` type everything works as expected.  The issue is that we are modifying the JSON object to include more information in the body which is preventing the serializer from knowing how to handle this.
Our new request is as follows.

```
{  
   "httpHeaders":{  
   },
   "payload":{  
    }
}
```

The "old" object we had received is now in the "payload".  Do I need to override a method, perhaps a [Media Formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a type that contains your Job type as a property named Payload with another property named HttpHeaders that contains the expected model structure. I don't know why you're sending Http headers in the payload body.

The model binding will attempt to match the structure of the request body to the structure of the expected model. In this case, you're going from expecting type Job, to accepting a type that contains Job. So, you would create a super type like this:

```
public class InputModel {
    public Job Payload {get;set;}
    public HeaderType HttpHeaders {get;set;}
}
```

The ASP.NET model binding will then populate the objects accordingly.

Comment: I assumed this was the case so I'll have to map the Payload to my Job model manually or could I just use the deserializer at this moment in the method?

Comment: If the payload object matches your Job model then all that you need to do is name the property Payload and have it be of the type Job. If the payload object does not match the Job model then you will need to provide serialization information so that the mapping can occur during model binding.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks much.  As an aside, this is passing through a message queue which is why the strange format.  It's being modified for the remote API calls.